Springboot - Failed to evaluate Jackson deserialization for type
I'm getting some problems with a API with 2 relations.
Model - coche
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "coches")
public class Coche {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String matricula;
    
    private String modelo;
    
    private String color;

    private boolean reservado=false;
    
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private NivelGasolina nivelGasolina;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "coche")
    @JsonBackReference
    private List<Booking> bookings;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

} 

Model - Booking
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "booking")


public class Booking {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private Integer roomNumber;

    // Serializa las fechas en el formato "día/mes/año"
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")
    private LocalDate fechaInicio;

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")
    private LocalDate fechaFin;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "coche_id" /* , nullable = false*/)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Coche coche;
}


Controller - Booking
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/booking")
@RequiredArgsConstructor

public class BookingController {

    private final BookingService bookingService;

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<Booking>> obteinAllBookings() {
            return ResponseEntity.ok(bookingService.obteinallBookings());
    }

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Booking> createNewBooking(@RequestBody Booking booking) {

    try {
        Booking createdBooking = bookingService.newBooking(booking);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(createdBooking);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error al crear la reserva : ---->> " + e.getMessage()); // Imprime el mensaje de error en la consola
        e.printStackTrace(); // Imprime el stack trace del error
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(null);
    }
}

Service - Booking
public class BookingService {
    private final BookingRepository bookingRepository;
    private final CocheRepository cocheRepository;

    public List<Booking> obteinallBookings() {
        return bookingRepository.findAll();
    }

    public Booking newBooking(Booking booking) {
        if (booking.getCoche() != null && booking.getCoche().getId() != null) {
            Coche cocheExistente = cocheRepository.findById(booking.getCoche().getId())
                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Coche no encontrado"));
            booking.setCoche(cocheExistente);
            cocheExistente.setReservado(true);
        }
        return bookingRepository.save(booking);
    }

    public Booking updateBooking(Long id, Booking booking) {
        Booking existBooking = bookingRepository.findById(id)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Booking no encontrado"));
            
        existBooking.setFechaInicio(booking.getFechaInicio());
        existBooking.setFechaFin(booking.getFechaFin());
        return bookingRepository.save(existBooking);
    }

    public void deteleBooking(Long id) {
        bookingRepository.deleteById(id);
    }
}

The problems its;
'coches' works fine with postman, I can get/update/delete, I had some data in the data.sql, some cars and 1 booking.
When I try GET on booking API works fine, I get this;
    {
        "id": 1,
        "roomNumber": 101,
        "fechaInicio": "01-10-2023",
        "fechaFin": "05-10-2023",
        "coche": {
            "id": 1,
            "matricula": "1234ABC",
            "modelo": "Toyota Corolla",
            "color": "#808080",
            "reservado": true,
            "nivelGasolina": "LLENO"
        }
    }
]

But if I try to POST on booking with this JSON;
{
    "roomNumber": 182,
    "fechaInicio": "2023-10-05",
    "fechaFin": "2023-10-08",
    "coche": {
        "id": 4
    }
}

I get this error;
2024-12-16T16:58:18.664Z  WARN 17972 --- [LucasRent] [nio-8080-exec-3] .c.j.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter : Failed to evaluate Jackson deserialization for type [[simple type, class com.lucas.fuel.LucasRent.model.Booking]]      

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot handle managed/back reference 'defaultReference': back reference type (`java.util.List<com.lucas.fuel.LucasRent.model.Booking>`) not compatible with managed type (com.lucas.fuel.LucasRent.model.Booking)

I dont know where is the problem, on postman I had tried to Header -> Content-type -> application/json but it dont works anyways..
I tried a lot, since types of consume json on the code...

the error states that the parser expects a list of booking, whieh the payload contains one object. indeed, it looks like the GET produces a list. did you try POSTing with a list of booking, containing the one item
